# How to use Win32 SetCursor() with WPF resource and HwndHost

Tags: wpf, winapi, cursor, resourcedictionary, hwndhost

We have an HwndHost UIElement in our WPF application which is used to display Direct3d graphics, and the only way I have found to set a cursor for the HwndHost UIElment is to call the Win32 API SetCursor().  All of our cursors are resources in managed assemblies, and I would prefer to not change that, but I have not been able to find a way to load one of these cursors via any Win32 APIs like LoadImage().

Does anybody know how to get a handle(hCursor) to a cursor which is a resource in a managed assembly?

Or, is there another way to set a cursor on an HwndHost displaying Direct3D graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique I've used in this situation before is:

```
DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadCursorFromFileW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)
public static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(String str);

...save your cursor into a temporary file...

IntPtr hCursor = DllImport.LoadCursorFromFile(sFilename);

...use hCursor in the SetCursor...
```

- make sure your cursor `.cur` files are added to your project as `"Embedded Resource"`
- determine/calculate the resource path to the cursor in your managed resources
- access the `Stream` to that cursor by using `GetManifestResourceStream`
- save that binary data into a temporary file
  (e.g. use `FileStream` with `FileMode.Create` and if you want `FileAttributes.Temporary`)
- use `LoadCursorFromFile` to load the data from the file and create a cursor handle which you can then use in SetCursor.
- clean up the temporary file

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292